# My CPU overheat when i'm using a mongo tailable cursor with .stream()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to use a tailable cursor with stream. We are using mongoose and it works but when I launch my server with this code :

```
const listStream = ListsSub.find()
  .tailable({
    await_data: true,
    numberOfRetries: -1,
  })
  .stream();
```

my CPU is overheating.

Activity Monitor when code is active

[image]

Commentating the `.stream()` make the server runs great again.

Activity Monitor when the code is in commented

[image]

I don't really know how to do without it.
Is it something with my code ? Anyone experienced the same problem ?

**EDIT :**

- mongoose : 4.11.3
- mongodb : 3.4.6
- node : 8.1.2
- Server and mongodb on the same machine

Comment: It's likely that the client is "polling" and not actually awaiting events in an efficient way. Mongoose version? And MongoDB version being connected to please. Also I presume both client and server are running on the same machine?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to ask for the `node` version as well. But it does actually seem to point more at `mongod` than anything else, and also in particular running on OSX.

Comment: We have the same problem when running on Ubuntu. It doesn't go as high on Ubuntu and it's not overheating but mongod is using ~80% CPU.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are actually doing on the tailable cursor? Is there lots of new data being read? Or is it mostly sitting idle through the high CPU usage?

Comment: It's mostly idle, there a no new documents to read and we're not doing anything else with it.

Comment: Well I actually see a significant (basically down to 0) drop on idle by simply using `.cursor()` instead of `.stream()`. There is in fact a deprecation warning being issued as `DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: Query.prototype.stream() is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.5.0, use Query.prototype.cursor() instead`

Comment: Indeed there is a DeprecationWarning on stream, but we still have the high percentage CPU use on the two OS with cursor. We tried to drop the collection `ListSub` just before launching the server and the same thing happens.
If we add `listStream .pause()` just after creating listStream, the CPU stays fine.

Comment: I should probably add that since submitting the answer that code is still running, and not even "breaking a sweat" let alone overworking the CPU. So that's over 30 minutes later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are actually a couple of things to do here. The first notable thing is to use the [`.cursor()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-stream) method instead of [`.stream()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-stream) as is actually indicated in the deprecation warning issued when used otherwise:

> DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: Query.prototype.stream() is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.5.0, use Query.prototype.cursor() instead

The second notable thing is that as specified in the [`.cursor()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-stream) documentation, this now returns the "wrapped stream" interface directly from the underlying driver. So it is then recommended to use the modern [`.addCursorFlag()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Cursor.html#addCursorFlag) options instead of the [`.tailable()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-tailable) method from mongoose `Query`.

Once both of those measures are in place, I see the idle CPU for both the `mongod` and `node` processes drop to `0%` in between update intervals.

This is best simulated with the following listing.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug',true);

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/tailing',
      options = { useMongoClient: true };

const subSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
},{
  capped: { size: 1024, max: 1000 }
});

const Sub = mongoose.model('Sub', subSchema);

function log(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2))
}

(async function() {

  try {

    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri,options);

    //await Sub.remove({});

    await Sub.insertMany(Array(50).fill(1).map((e,i) => ({ name: i+1 })));

    let stream = Sub.find()
      .cursor()
      .addCursorFlag('tailable',true)
      .addCursorFlag('awaitData',true);
      /*
      .tailable({
        await_data: true,
        numberOfRetries: -1
      })
      .cursor();
      */

    stream.on('data',function(data) {
      log(data);
    });

    let counter = 50;


    setInterval(async function() {
      counter++;
      await Sub.insertMany({ name: counter });
    },10000);

  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  } finally {
    //mongoose.disconnect();
  }

})();
```

Plain old top output, captured as an actual write takes place:

```
top - 21:38:29 up 12 days,  1:23,  3 users,  load average: 0.06, 0.03, 0.04
Tasks: 116 total,   2 running, 114 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.3 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 98.6 id,  0.7 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  2045968 total,   207452 free,   813908 used,  1024608 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  2097148 total,  2097124 free,       24 used.  1028156 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 1257 mongodb   20   0 1946896 487336  34892 S  0.7 23.8 130:37.67 mongod
28233 neillunn  20   0 1021460  41920  22996 S  0.3  2.0   0:00.67 node
30956 neillunn  20   0  101472   4384   3352 S  0.3  0.2   0:20.95 sshd
```

Comment: This answer also applies to the native mongodb driver, except that the `find()` already returns a cursor, so you don't have to call `cursor()`.

Answer (score 0):

I am using mongooseV5.9.2 and I needed to add below way to fix the issue

```
let options = { tailable: true, 
                awaitData: true, 
                numberOfRetries: -1, 
                tailableRetryInterval: 200
              };
    collection.find().cursor(options);
```